# Ubuntu: "DocumentRoot does not exit"

Tags: zend-framework, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

That is my code:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot var\www\public
    ServerName my_ip
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/public">
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But have error:

> [Mon Feb 25 01:38:54 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no
>   VirtualHosts
>       ... waiting Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/apache2/var\www\public] does not exist
>       apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using  "my_ip" for ServerName
>
> [Mon Feb 25 01:38:55 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Why DocumentRoot search in `/etc/apache2/var\`, as I wrote `var\www\public`

That fix my problem: `/var/www/public`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [QSA,L]` instead of `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]`? You don't need `NC` for that condition, and `QSA` is adding request query string (don't think it's fixes the problem though). And it's always leaving after that rule as it is now (because of `^.*$`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu does not use backslash `\` as a path separator, it uses `/`. Since it does not understand the path separator, it takes the path as a relative path from `/etc/apache/var` instead of an absolute path.

Use `/var/www/public` as a document root instead.

Comment: Now write: [Mon Feb 25 01:48:59 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain n
ame, using my-ip for ServerName

Comment: Just edit your /etc/hosts file accordingly to get rid of that warning.

Comment: @WarKings Try `grep NameVirtualHost *` in your config directory, it should only exist once (in the file displayed above) and you probably have two. I've had problems with it surfacing in ports.conf.